# How to change font type of plots in R?

Tags: r, plot, pie-chart

I have a pie chart in an R-language script. I want the legends and the numbers in Times New Roman fount, but despite that I have seen many solutions in google, none of them works. My code is the following:

```r
library("readr")
library("fmsb")
library("car")
library("normtest")
library("nortest")
library("moments")
library("readxl")  
library("ggplot2")
library("stats")
library("lsr")

categorias <-c("Básica",
              "Media",
              "Superior (IP o CFT)",
              "Superior universitaria",
              "Postrado")
contar <-c(10,
          27,
          15,
          16,
          1)
par(family="Times New Roman")
piepercent<- round(100*contar/sum(contar), 2)
lbls <- paste(piepercent) # add percents to labels
lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="")
png(file="NIVEL_EDUCACIONAL.eps")
pie(contar, radius=1.0,labels = lbls,col = rainbow(length(contar)))
legend("topleft",categorias, cex = 0.9, fill = rainbow(length(contar)))
dev.off()
```

any ideas? Thanks in advance and greetings :D

Answer (score 0):

`Times New Roman` is often the default serif font. Use `windowsFonts()` to verify. Then call the default instead of the specific font:

```
par(family = 'serif')
```